# Difference of cakephp2 and Cakephp3

Tags: cakephp

I think entirely different in folder structure Cakephp 2.0 and Cakephp 3.0 Could please explain about some functionality like how to set primary_key in Table and how to use "use_table" syntax in cakephp 3.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **Better performance :**

  Version 3 incorporates performance improvements to the bootstrap process, the routing process, and several parts of process for generating helper templates.
- **Enhanced components and helpers:**

  Version 3 provides enhanced support for “flash messages” with its new FlashHelper and FlashComponent. In addition, the CookieComponent has been enhanced, making it easier to separate the configuration of cookie namespaces and the handling of cookie data.
- **Improved session management:**

  Session management has always been a static class in CakePHP which has proven to be problematic in a number of ways. With version 3, you can now access the session from the request object $this->request->session(). This change also makes the session easier to test, and enables CakePHP to use PHPUnit 4.x.
- **Improved consistency of conventions:**

  The application skeleton and plugin skeletons have been updated to use the same directory structure in order to be more consistent with one another.
- **Themes and plugins merged:**

  A key goal of CakePHP 3 was to make themes more powerful and robust. Working toward that goal, it became apparent that what was really needed was for themes to provide the same capabilities as plugins. Accordingly, any plugin may now be used as a theme, which also simplifies packaging and redistribution.
- **ORM Improvements:**

  Several API changes have been made to the ORM (Object-relational mapping). Most notably, it’s now simpler to specify deep associations for saving operations, and a couple of conventions have been changed to reduce the learning curve and confusion among new adopters.

In addition, there are a few additional features that are also planned to be incorporated into the beta release of version 3.0. Most importantly:

- Internationalization and localization (i18n and L10n) feature enhancements
- A replacement for CacheHelper based on Edge Side Includes
- A new routing API for simpler and faster route declaration

Indeed, version 3 represents a significant upgrade beyond prior versions of CakePHP.

> This review is based on the [alpha release of CakePHP 3.0](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lorenzo/2014/06/25/cakephp_3_0_0-alpha1_released), which incorporates a number of new features and enhancements including:

**Syntax difference**

For syntax difference between cakephp 2.0 and cakephp 3.0, you need to read the following article

- Blog Tutorial in CakPHP 2.x

  [Blog Tutorial 2.x](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html)
- Blog Tutorial in CakPHP 3.x

  [Blog Tutorial 3.x](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html)

Comment: Hi, I have asked some syntax difference between cakephp 2.0 and cakephp 3.0 It will very helpful for others.

Comment: Hi, Karthik, I'm update my answer, see the **Syntax difference** section.